# decode data using jquery in yii

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii, model

My controller action in YII is as below.

```
$keyword=$_POST['email'];

        $match = addcslashes($keyword, '%_'); 
        $query = new CDbCriteria( array(
            'condition' => "username LIKE :match",         
            'params'    => array(':match' => "%$match%")  
        ) );

        $comments = Login::model()->findAll( $query );

        header('Content-type: application/json');

        echo CJavaScript::jsonEncode($comments);
        Yii::app()->end();
```

I am sending an ajax request. As a result of above action I got following.
[{"id":"4","userid":"4","teamid":null,"username":"c@gmail.com","password":"abc123","perm":"full","utype":"user"}]

> In my ajax success function I want to print the username value only.
>   According to the result I want to print 'c@gmail.com'.How can I do
>   that? I tried as following.

```
 success: function (data) {
            alert(data.username);
        }
```

It didn't work. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are making ajax request then set **datatype to json**

```
$.ajax({
url: '',
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data){
alert(data[0].username); // change this too
}

});
```

**Updated**

You can use **$.each()** to access each element of the array

eg:-

```
$.each(data,function(index,element){
alert(element.username);
});
```

Comment: It worked well.Thank you so much for correct answer and quick reply:)

Comment: My pleasure friend :)

Comment: If my action result gives more than one array, how to loop through each array. eg: {"id":"4","userid":"4","teamid":null,"username":"c@gmail.com","password":"abc123","perm":"full","utype":"user"},{"id":"5","userid":"8","teamid":null,"username":"chd@gmail.com","password":"abc123","perm":"full","utype":"user"} I want to print  all 2 user names. That is 'c@gmail.com','chd@gmail.com'